# PHP MYSQL IN condition for category id take time

Tags: mysql

Product Table : product_id (int), cat_id (int).

Query :

```
SELECT * FROM products where cat_id IN()
```

Product table having 1000000 rows

If cat_id having more cat_id like cat_id IN (2,3,4,5,6) take much time compare to cat_id IN (2) for execution query. Please give me proper way for query or any change in database schema.

Answer (score 1):

Create an index on `products(cat_id)`:

```
create index idx_products_catid on products(cat_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

STored procedures http://www.mysqltutorial.org/introduction-to-sql-stored-procedures.aspx

The above link gives an introduction to Stored procedure. I am not sure if it will improve your performance but its worth a shot since you would like to make your query execute quicker.

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx

Just look through the above link. It will give you an idea to write stored procedure.

Comment: That i have already done. Is there any changes in field structure od cat_id in products table?

Comment: @user3239664 I don't see anyother imrpovements you can do that query. wHow long does it take to execute the query?

Comment: around 5 sec and for single cat_id it takes 1.5 sec

Comment: @user3239664 But 5 seconds is good. Its not that long. I have seen queries wqhich takes 20 seconds to exceute.

Comment: Its only taking longer because the IN statement contains more values @user3239664

Comment: Any other alternate ?

Comment: What tools did you use to write the query and execute? @user3239664

Comment: I am using PHP/MSQL webbased website and check using phpmyadmin of cpanel

Comment: Oh right, I only asked you that because, if you use SQL Server, they provide an excution plan tool which can help you perform faster. I am sorry, I have got no idea.

Comment: Oh Yh, my other solution is to add a stored procedure, you can try adding a stored procedure which may increase the performance of a query @user3239664

Comment: Could you please give me any example or reference link for stored procedure having same issue. So that i can understand and create stored procedure for products table.

Comment: I just edited my answer to stored procedures. Have a look @user3239664